# Global Values return to Original Values After AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global-variables

I am relatively new to jQuery, I am trying to work around this code but constantly failing, the problem I'm facing is, I have a gloval array (Roles_Permission), I am able to use this in my AJAX request, I am also able to make changes to the Array's content but the moment I come out, all the global values return to original ones, Why?!? Need help. Please look at the following code,

```
// Global Variable
var Role_Permission = {
    "Value1" : true;
    "Value2" : true;
    "Value3" : true;
}
```

Now I have a function which is as follows,

```
function checkRoles(){
    requestData(
        "roleData",
        { roleName: "testUser"},
        function(result){
            Role_Permission["Value2"] = false;
            alert(Role_Permission["Value2"]);
        }
    });

    alert(Role_Permission["Value2"]);
}
```

The alert outside AJAX returns value of Value2 as True however, inside it returns as FALSE, Why?!? Please help

Thankyou

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because AJAX request run asynchronously, which is why you are giving it a callback that will be called once it is done. Everything outside the callback will be executed right away even while the request you just sent is still running. This is why the bottom alert still has the old value, but the one inside the callback the new one.

Comment: Someone has to develop an AI to automatically detect (an answer) this kind of question...

Comment: Yeah I know. Just tried it, but the auto suggest failed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, really stupid of me not to take asynchronous running into account. Problem fixed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: ajax explained]
<sub>(source: [fixingthesejquery.com](http://fixingthesejquery.com/images/ajax101.png))</sub>