# global variable in javascript to get Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

i am using the following code to access the geolocation of the blackberry device. its working and showing the desire result. but i want to access the window.GlobalVar outside the body of this function. how can i access it? please help.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
  var gps = (position.coords.latitude+position.coords.longitude);  
  window.GlobalVar = gps;
  alert (window.GlobalVar);
});
```

Best regards,

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809690/global-values-return-to-original-values-after-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.GlobalVar` will be accessible outside of your function.

What's probably going wrong here is that you're trying to access it before it has been set, seeing as it is being set in a callback function.

`getCurrentPosition` prompts the user for coordinates, but it is not a blocking call, i.e. it does not simply halt all code execution and wait for the user to make a decision.

This means that you do *not* set `window.GlobalVar` during page load, you *request* it during page load, and you set it *whenever the user decides to*. So no matter where you call `getCurrentPosition` you cannot be sure that at a given point, `window.GlobalVar` will be set.

If you want to be sure that `window.GlobalVar` is set in the script you're running, you need to make sure that you're running the script *after* the variable has been set.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
  var gps = (position.coords.latitude+position.coords.longitude);  
  window.GlobalVar = gps;

  continueSomeProcess();
});

function continueSomeProcess() {
   // this code will be able to access window.GlobalVar
}
```

Comment: i am setting it onload, and trying to access it at the end of the page.

Comment: @asifhameed: No, you are not setting it onload, you are *asking* for it onload. When you get it is out of your control, and you may never get it, if the user elects not to share it. At the end of the page it will most likely not be set, because the script at the end of the page will be executed immediately as the site renders, and before the user has a chance to react to the request. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `window.gps` after setting `window.gps = gps` should be enough as it has a global scope since you attached it to `window`. Take care of the fact that JS is asynchronous, ie `gps` might not be defined when you call it.

Comment: i am setting my global variable onload, and trying to access it at the end of the page.